# Column-count > 1 increases the height of the parent inline-block element

Tags: css, html, safari, css-multicolumn-layout

When changing the column-count of a div nested in an inline-block tag (or a block tag set to display: inline-block) the height of this inline-block tag is multiplied by the column-count number of the nested div.

When you run the snippet, you'll see the blue bordered box having the height 
doubled. With `column-count: 3` the height will triple, with 4 it will quadruple, etc.

Why is this?

```css
main {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

article {
  display: inline-block;
}

#text {
  column-count: 2;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <main>
      <article>
        <div id="text">
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras sed augue eu arcu eleifend iaculis. Vestibulum sem enim, pharetra vel orci a, tempor eleifend ligula. Fusce in congue nibh, ac dignissim velit. In in metus tempor, placerat est sed, luctus ipsum. Fusce tellus nulla, fringilla sed neque eget, imperdiet commodo ante. Quisque id arcu at purus suscipit vestibulum. Vestibulum cursus nunc mauris, quis vestibulum tellus finibus vitae. Morbi ut tincidunt felis, ut viverra sapien. Donec dictum, lacus sit amet laoreet consectetur, augue turpis posuere metus, eget consequat elit arcu non sem.
          </p>
        </div>
      </article>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Which browser are you using?seems to be working fine on chrome

Comment: Yes, you are right, works in Chrome. I should have mentioned that this is in Safari 11.1

Comment: It also displays a bit oddly in Firefox (v61).